# The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MPinController'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm flutter begginner and faced problem with these code below.

1. The Widget MPinWidget is in mpin_widget.dart.
2. In mpin_page, I import that mpin_widget and in build method, try to use like below. but It has error but I don't get how to arrange this. Could you advice to this?

   ```
      class MPinWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   final MPinController controller;
   final int pinLegth;
   final Function(String) onCompleted;

   MPinWidget(
       {Key?key, @required required this.pinLegth, required this.controller, required this.onCompleted})
       : assert(pinLegth <= 6 && pinLegth > 0),
         super(key: key);
   @override
   _MPinWidgetState createState() => _MPinWidgetState(controller);
   ```

}

```
 SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                MPinWidget (
                  pinLegth: 5,
                  onCompleted: (String ) {  },
                    controller: MPinController controller),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
controller: MPinController controller
```

to

```
controller: widget.controller
```